# What is the Space Complexity of Passing by Reference

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, space-complexity

I was reading [this](https://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/311/html/space-complexity.html) website to learn about space complexity. It mentioned the following scenario:

A function is written in a language that is pass by value. So whenever an argument is passed, new memory is allocated for the local variable. However, you pass a *pointer* to a variable instead, so you are passing by reference.

The website said that this would not allocate new space for a local variable, because you are passing by reference, so the variable already exists in memory, and the memory is then shared.

But wouldn't it still create a local variable that was a pointer to the memory location? And, as a result, allocate new memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; there is a single word of memory allocated in the stack frame for that call.  What they intend to convey is that you're not allocating memory for the existing variable (e.g. 1kb for a 1000-character string).  Formally, this allocation is **O(1)** rather than the **O(n)** you get from pass by value.

***If*** you don't consider the stack to be part of the process's memory, then you have a zero-cost allocation for this case.  Also, note that **O(1)** space overhead will *not* increase the complexity for any algorithm, so it's theoretically okay to ignore.  It's valid, although it *does* smell strange to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't much about space complexity but references are normally passed on the stack.  Some systems hold this entirely in a register especially if the function is in lined and hence no memory allocation.

Also note huge difference between register , stack and heap in terms of performance , safety etc.